# Google App Script getThreads() problem with Gmail conversations - Do not see mails with same title

Tags: google-apps-script

I meet a problem while my script is working perfectly, it is difficult on new threads.
I have turned off conversations in Gmail, but it still read-only first message at a certain date with the same title. Every time first, even when new mail arrives it see it as the first email received with a certain title. Is there a way to make the app script see new emails with the same title?

```
var hbNewLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Example")
var hb = hbNewLabel.getThreads()
var countNew = hb.length

  for (a=countNew -1; a>=0; a--){
var message = hb[a].getMessages()
var mailText = message[0].getPlainBody()

}
```

Comment: From your question it is difficult to understand what the problem is. Remember that switching conversation view, is only a [visual option](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop), and does not affect Gmail grouping the emails in threads. As you are calling the first message in the thread (`message[0]`), I think this is the expected behavior. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks that solve the problem partialy.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand your goal. Please, can you update your question to reflect exactly what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail option [Group emails into conversations](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900) is a visual option, and does not affect the thread behavior.

Therefore, the behavior you describe is what is expected from Apps Script and you will have to adjust your script to meet your requirements.